# Ultraweak continuity implies norm continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ are Hilbert spaces, $\mathcal{U}\subset B(\mathcal{H})$ is a C$^*$-algebra, and $\eta:\mathcal{U}\rightarrow B(\mathcal{K})$ is a linear map that is ultraweakly continuous on the closed unit ball $(\mathcal{U})_{1}$ of $\mathcal{U}$. For $x,y\in \mathcal{K}$, the linear functinal $\omega_{x,y}\circ\eta$ on $\mathcal{U}$ is ultraweakly continuous ($\omega_{x,y}$ is the functional defined by $\omega_{x,y}(A)=\langle Ax,y\rangle$ for $A\in B(\mathcal{K})$). My question is why does this imply that $\omega_{x,y}\circ\eta$ is also norm continuous on $(\mathcal{U})_{1}$? I don't have any reason to think the ultraweak topology is coarser than the norm topology (if $\mathcal{U}$ is a von Neumann algebra then norm continuity would follow from the fact that the unit ball of $\mathcal{U}$ is weak operator compact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you made the codomain the scalars, the topology problems on the codomain side disappear.

If $A_n\to A $ in norm, then $A_n\to A$ ultraweakly. Then $\omega_{x,y}(A_n)\to\omega_{x,y}(A)$. Thus $\omega_{x,y}$ is norm-continuous.

Comment: Why does $A_{n}\rightarrow A$ ultraweakly? I’m not sure how to use your first comment about the codomain.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? How do you define ultraweak convergence?

Comment: As the weak topology with respect to the functionals $A\mapsto \sum\langle A_{x_{n}},y_{n}\rangle$ where $\{x_{n}\},\{y_{n}\}$ are square summable

Comment: I think I see why this is true. So convergence in these various topologies isn’t related to one being coarser than another?

Comment: E.g. I was thinking that norm convergence implies weak operator convergence because the latter is coarser than the former. But maybe this isn’t related?

Comment: The norm topology is stronger/finer than the ultraweak topology. This in particular implies that convergence in norm implies ultraweak convergence. Continuity goes the other way: because it is easier to converge ultraweakly, it is harder to be continuous. In this case, it is trivial to check from your definition that those functionals are bounded, so norm-continuous.

Comment: Yes, I see now that the ultraweak topology is in fact coarser